# ModuleNotFoundError in Jupyter Notebook for Python 3 but not Python 2 (Mac OSX)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, macos, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use Pandas in a Python 3 Jupyter Notebook on a Mac (OSX High Sierra 10.13.6), but I get the following error when I run `import pandas as pd`:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I have the same issue with Numpy and other Python packages.

This problem does NOT occur when I try the same thing in a Python 2 Jupyter Notebook on the same system.

Please see the links to screen shots below:

[Jupyter Notebook Python 3 Import Pandas Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t60nb.png)

[Jupyter Notebook Python 2 Import Pandas NO Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj4Of.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Different versions of Python have different package lists. Depending on if you're using pip, Anaconda, or some other package manager, you'll need to install your packages for the version of Python you intend to use them with.

Comment: I use Anaconda-Navigator, so I went into it to open a command line and run: conda update --all. It didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have solved my problem by installing the latest version of Anaconda, Anaconda 3. I don't know if this is the most precise or elegant solution (seems a bit like rebuilding a house to fix a broken pipe) but it worked.

If anyone has any other advice, I'm happy to hear it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue again (on a new computer) and this time reinstalling the latest version of Anaconda isn't solving the problem. Help, please!